# How to speedup very long expressions calculations using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is a part of a function that is intended to calculate the loop gain of a circuit. Then, I use it to compute the phase margin. I divided the expression into multiple lines with multiple variables so as to speedup the calculations. Furthermore, I use 's' as a variable instead of using it as a 'tf' or 'syms'. The problem is I call this function thousands of times. **So is there other tips and tricks to push its speed to the limit?**
**Note:**  This is a part of the expression. And the function has two other longer expressions than the one attached. Also, the variables are changing every time I call them.

```
 s=w*i; 
 gm0=75.3546e-6; gm1=31.2754e-6; gm2=31.2754e-6; gm3=59.8581e-6; gm4=59.8581e-6; gm5=37.4835e-6; 
 gm6=37.4835e-6; gmb5=8.65e-6; gmb6=8.65e-6; gm7=50.2003e-6; gm8=50.2003e-6; gm9=37.7087e-6; 
 gm10=37.7087e-6; gm11=49.963e-6; gmQ1=42.94e-6; gmQ2=42.86e-6;  goQ1=15.86e-6; goQ2=15.9e-6;
 go0=107.622e-9; go1=45.307e-9; go2=45.307e-9; go3=98.159e-9; go4=98.159e-9; go5=49.4627e-9; 
 go6=49.4641e-9; go7=63.339e-9; go8=63.339e-9; go9=56.2222e-9; go10=56.2187e-9;  go11=65.0619e-9;
 R1=35.381e3; R2=383.23e3; R3=383.23e3; R4=301.8e3;
 cgs0=1.155e-12; cgs1=364.5e-15; cgs2=364.5e-15; cgs3=106.8e-15; cgs4=106.8e-15; cgs5=95.3e-15; 
 cgs6=95.3e-15; cgs7=765.862e-15; cgs8=765.862e-15; cgs9=581.38e-15; cgs10=581.38e-15; 
 cgs11=765.853e- 
 15;
 cdg0=22.5e-15; cdg1=6.26e-15; cdg2=6.26e-15; cdg3=2.36e-15; cdg4=2.36e-15; cdg5=2.14e-15; 
 cdg6=2.14e- 
 15; cdg7=13.71e-15; cdg8=13.71e-15; cdg9=11.62e-15; cdg10=11.62e-15; cdg11=14.09e-15;
 cdb0=37.5e-15; cdb1=17.07e-15; cdb2=17.07e-15; cdb3=2.94e-15; cdb4=2.94e-15; cdb5=4.06e-15; 
 cdb6=4.06e-15; cdb9=31.79e-15; cdb10=31.796e-15; cdb7=35.793e-15; cdb8=35.793e-15; cdb11=38.44e-15;
 csb5=26.5e-15; csb6=26.5e-15; cpi1=346.5e-15; cpi2=44.19e-15; cbc2=39.72e-15; cbc1=317.78e-15;
 cgb5=13.35e-15; cgb6=13.35e-15;   csb5=28.9e-15; csb6=28.9e-15;
 cgb7=102e-15; cgb8=102e-15; cgb11=102e-15;
 RQ1=17006.8;
 cdgdb0=60e-15; cdgdb3=5.3e-15; cdgdb5=6.2e-15; cgsdb9gs10=1194.55e-15;  cgsgb7811=2603.577e-15;  
 cdgdb3gs5=100.6e-15; cgsdb9gs10dgdb5=1200.75e-15; cdb10dgdb6=37.996e-15;
 cgsgb7811pi2=2647.767e-15; go7R3=2.6727e-6; go8R2=2.6727e-6;  go11R4=3.3785e-6;  gmgoQ1=58.8e-6;   
 gmgoQ2=58.76e-6; cgsgb7811cpi2=2647.767e-15;
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 goa=go5 + go9 + cdg10*s + cgsdb9gs10dgdb5*s;
 gob=2*go1 + cdgdb0*s + 2*cgs1*s;
 goc=go1 + go3 + go5 + cdg1*s + cdgdb3gs5*s;
 god=go1 + go3 + go5 + cdg1*s + cdgdb3gs5*s;
 goe= goQ1 + cpi1*s + 1/R1;
 gof=go5 + go10 + cdb10dgdb6*s + cdg10*s;
 gog=go11R4 + cdb11*s + cdg11*s;
 goh=go8R2 + cdb8*s + cdg1*s + cdg8*s + cgs1*s + 1/R1;
 goi=go7R3 + goQ2 + cdb7*s + cdg1*s + cdg7*s + cgs1*s + cpi2*s;
 goj=cdg7*s + cdg8*s + cdg11*s + cgsgb7811*s;
 gok=goQ1 + cpi1*s;
 goL=goQ2 + cpi2*s;
 goM= - goQ1 - cpi1*s;
 goN= - goQ1 - cpi1*s;
 goO= - goQ2 - cpi2*s;
 goP= - goQ2 - cpi2*s;



tic

A0=gmQ2*go1^2*go5^2 + go1^2*go5^2*goi + 2.0*cdg1^2*gm1*go5^2*s^2 + cdg1^2*gm9*go1^2*s^2 - 
1.0*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*s^2 + cdg1^2*go1^2*goa*s^2 + cdg1^2*go5^2*gob*s^2 + cgs1^2*gm5*go5^2*s^2 + 
cgs1^2*gm5^2*go5*s^2 - 1.0*cgs1^2*gm5^2*goa*s^2 + cgs1^2*go5^2*goc*s^2 + 2.0*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ2 - 
2.0*gm1*gm5*gmQ2*go5^2 - 2.0*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ2*go5 - 2.0*gm5*gm9*gmQ2*go1^2 + 2.0*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*goi + 
2.0*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ2*goa + gm5^2*gm9*gmQ2*gob + gm1*gmQ2*go1*go5^2 + gm5*gmQ2*go1^2*go5 - 
2.0*gm1*gm5*go5^2*goi - 2.0*gm1*gm5^2*go5*goi - 2.0*gm5*gm9*go1^2*goi - 2.0*gm5*gmQ2*go1^2*goa - 
1.0*gm5*gmQ2*go5^2*gob - 1.0*gm5^2*gmQ2*go5*gob - 2.0*gm1*gmQ2*go5^2*goc - 1.0*gm9*gmQ2*go1^2*goc - 
1.0*gm9*gmQ2*go1^2*god + 2.0*gm1*gm5^2*goa*goi + gm5^2*gm9*gob*goi + gm5^2*gmQ2*goa*gob + 
 gm1*go1*go5^2*goi + gm5*go1^2*go5*goi - 2.0*gm5*go1^2*goa*goi - 1.0*gm5*go5^2*gob*goi - 
 1.0*gm5^2*go5*gob*goi - 2.0*gm1*go5^2*goc*goi - 1.0*gm9*go1^2*goc*goi - 1.0*gm9*go1^2*god*goi - 
 1.0*gmQ2*go1^2*goa*goc - 1.0*gmQ2*go1^2*goa*god - 1.0*gmQ2*go5^2*gob*goc + gm5^2*goa*gob*goi - 
 1.0*go1^2*goa*goc*goi - 1.0*go1^2*goa*god*goi - 1.0*go5^2*gob*goc*goi - 1.0*cdg1*gm1^2*go5^2*s + 
 cdg1*cgs1*gm1*go5^2*s^2 + 2.0*cdg1*cgs1*go1*go5^2*s^2 - 2.0*cdg1^2*gm1*gm5*gm9*s^2 + 
 2.0*cdg1^2*gm1*gm5*go5*s^2 + cdg1^2*gm1*gm9*go1*s^2 - 2.0*cdg1^2*gm1*gm5*goa*s^2 - 
 1.0*cdg1^2*gm5*gm9*gob*s^2 - 2.0*cdg1^2*gm1*gm9*god*s^2 + cdg1^2*gm1*go1*goa*s^2 + 
 cdg1^2*gm5*go5*gob*s^2 - 1.0*cdg1^2*gm5*goa*gob*s^2 - 2.0*cdg1^2*gm1*goa*god*s^2 ;
 A1=- 1.0*cdg1^2*gm9*gob*god*s^2 - 1.0*cgs1^2*gm5*gm9*goc*s^2 - 1.0*cgs1^2*gm5*gm9*god*s^2 - 
 1.0*cdg1^2*goa*gob*god*s^2 + cgs1^2*gm5*go5*goc*s^2 - 1.0*cgs1^2*gm5*goa*goc*s^2 - 
 1.0*cgs1^2*gm5*goa*god*s^2 - 1.0*cgs1^2*gm9*goc*god*s^2 - 1.0*cgs1^2*goa*goc*god*s^2 - 
 2.0*gm1*gm5*gm9*gmQ2*go1 + 2.0*gm1*gm5*gm9*gmQ2*goc + 2.0*gm1*gm5*gm9*gmQ2*god + 
 gm1*gm5*gmQ2*go1*go5 - 2.0*gm1*gm5*gm9*go1*goi - 2.0*gm1*gm5*gmQ2*go1*goa - 2.0*gm1*gm5*gmQ2*go5*goc 
 - 1.0*gm1*gm9*gmQ2*go1*goc - 1.0*gm1*gm9*gmQ2*go1*god + 2.0*gm1*gm5*gm9*goc*goi + 
 2.0*gm1*gm5*gm9*god*goi + 2.0*gm1*gm5*gmQ2*goa*goc + 2.0*gm1*gm5*gmQ2*goa*god + gm5*gm9*gmQ2*gob*goc 
 + gm5*gm9*gmQ2*gob*god + 2.0*gm1*gm9*gmQ2*goc*god + gm1*gm5*go1*go5*goi - 2.0*gm1*gm5*go1*goa*goi - 
 2.0*gm1*gm5*go5*goc*goi - 1.0*gm1*gm9*go1*goc*goi - 1.0*gm1*gm9*go1*god*goi - 
 1.0*gm1*gmQ2*go1*goa*goc - 1.0*gm1*gmQ2*go1*goa*god - 1.0*gm5*gmQ2*go5*gob*goc + 
 2.0*gm1*gm5*goa*goc*goi + 2.0*gm1*gm5*goa*god*goi + gm5*gm9*gob*goc*goi + gm5*gm9*gob*god*goi + 
 2.0*gm1*gm9*goc*god*goi + gm5*gmQ2*goa*gob*goc + gm5*gmQ2*goa*gob*god + 2.0*gm1*gmQ2*goa*goc*god + 
 gm9*gmQ2*gob*goc*god - 1.0*gm1*go1*goa*goc*goi - 1.0*gm1*go1*goa*god*goi - 1.0*gm5*go5*gob*goc*goi + 
 gm5*goa*gob*goc*goi + gm5*goa*gob*god*goi + 2.0*gm1*goa*goc*god*goi + gm9*gob*goc*god*goi + 
 gmQ2*goa*gob*goc*god + goa*gob*goc*god*goi + cdg1*gm1^2*gm5*gm9*s - 1.0*cdg1*gm1*gm9*go1^2*s - 
 1.0*cdg1*gm1^2*gm5*go5*s - 1.0*cdg1*gm1^2*gm9*go1*s + cdg1*gm1^2*gm5*goa*s + cdg1*gm1^2*gm9*god*s - 
 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*s + cdg1*gm1*go1*go5^2*s - 1.0*cdg1*gm1*go1^2*goa*s - 
 1.0*cdg1*gm1^2*go1*goa*s ;
  A2=- 1.0*cdg1*gm1*go5^2*gob*s + cdg1*gm1^2*goa*god*s + cgs1*gm1*gm5*go5^2*s + cgs1*gm1*gm5^2*go5*s 
 - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5^2*goa*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*go1*go5^2*s + cgs1*gm1*go5^2*goc*s - 
 1.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm1*gm5*gm9*s^2 + cdg1*cgs1*gm1*gm5*go5*s^2 - 2.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm5*gm9*go1*s^2 - 
 1.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm1*gm5*goa*s^2 - 1.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm1*gm9*god*s^2 + 2.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm5*go1*go5*s^2 - 
 2.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm5*go1*goa*s^2 - 2.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm9*go1*god*s^2 - 1.0*cdg1*cgs1*gm1*goa*god*s^2 - 
 2.0*cdg1*cgs1*go1*goa*god*s^2 + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1^2*gm9*gmQ1*s^3 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1^2*gm9*goe*s^3 + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1^2*gmQ1*goa*s^3 + 
  2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1^2*goa*goe*s^3 + R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ1*go5^2*s^4 + 
 R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*go5^2*goe*s^4 - 1.0*cdg1*gm1*gm5*gm9*go1*s + cdg1*gm1*gm5*gm9*gob*s + 
 cdg1*gm1*gm5*go1*go5*s - 1.0*cdg1*gm1*gm5*go1*goa*s - 1.0*cdg1*gm1*gm5*go5*gob*s - 
 1.0*cdg1*gm1*gm9*go1*god*s + cdg1*gm1*gm5*goa*gob*s + cdg1*gm1*gm9*gob*god*s + 
 cgs1*gm1*gm5*gm9*go1*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5*gm9*goc*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5*gm9*god*s - 
 1.0*cdg1*gm1*go1*goa*god*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5*go1*go5*s + cdg1*gm1*goa*gob*god*s + 
 cgs1*gm1*gm5*go1*goa*s + cgs1*gm1*gm5*go5*goc*s + cgs1*gm1*gm9*go1*god*s - 
 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5*goa*goc*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm5*goa*god*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*gm9*goc*god*s + 
 cgs1*gm1*go1*goa*god*s - 1.0*cgs1*gm1*goa*goc*god*s - 1.0*R1^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*go5^2*goh - 
 1.0*R1^2*gmQ2*go1^2*go5^2*goe*goh - 1.0*R1^2*gmQ1*go1^2*go5^2*goh*goi - 
 1.0*R1^2*go1^2*go5^2*goe*goh*goi - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gm1*gm9*gmQ1*s^4 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gm1*gm9*goe*s^4 
 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gm1*gmQ1*goa*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gm9*gmQ1*gob*s^4 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gm1*goa*goe*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gm9*gob*goe*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*gmQ1*goa*gob*s^4 
 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^4*goa*gob*goe*s^4 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gm1*gm9*gmQ1*s^4 - 
 4.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gm9*gmQ1*go1*s^4 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gm1*gm9*goe*s^4 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gm1*gmQ1*goa*s^4 ;
 A3=- 4.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gm9*go1*goe*s^4 - 4.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gmQ1*go1*goa*s^4 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*gm1*goa*goe*s^4 - 4.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*cgs1*go1*goa*goe*s^4 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*gm9*gmQ1*go1*s^3 + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*gm9*gmQ1*gob*s^3 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*gm9*go1*goe*s^3 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*gmQ1*go1*goa*s^3 + 
 R1^2*cdg1*gm1^2*gmQ1*go5^2*goh*s + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*gm9*gob*goe*s^3 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*gmQ1*goa*gob*s^3 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*go1*goa*goe*s^3 + 
 R1^2*cdg1*gm1^2*go5^2*goe*goh*s + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^3*gm1*goa*gob*goe*s^3 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1*gm1^2*gm9*gmQ1*s^3 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gm9*gmQ1*s^4 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1*cgs1*gm1^2*gmQ1*go5^2*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1*cgs1^2*gm1*gmQ1*go5^2*s^3 + 
 R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1*gm1*gmQ1*go5^2*s^3 + R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gmQ1*go5*s^4 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1*gm1^2*gm9*goe*s^3 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gm9*goe*s^4 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1*gm1^2*gmQ1*goa*s^3 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gmQ1*goa*s^4 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm9*gmQ1*goc*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm9*gmQ1*god*s^4 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1*cgs1*gm1^2*go5^2*goe*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1*cgs1^2*gm1*go5^2*goe*s^3 + 
 R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1*gm1*go5^2*goe*s^3 + R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*go5*goe*s^4 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1*gm1^2*goa*goe*s^3 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*goa*goe*s^4 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm9*goc*goe*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gm9*god*goe*s^4 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ1*goa*goc*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ1*goa*god*s^4 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*goa*goc*goe*s^4 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*cgs1^2*goa*god*goe*s^4 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*gm9*gmQ1*go1*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*gm9*gmQ1*gob*s^2 + R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*s^2 + 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*gm9*go1*goe*s^2 + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*gmQ1*go1*goa*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm9*gmQ2*go1^2*goe*s^2 - 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1*gmQ1*go5^2*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm9*gmQ1*go1^2*goh*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm9*gmQ1*go1^2*goi*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*gm9*gob*goe*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*goa*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*gmQ1*goa*gob*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5^2*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5*s^2 + R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ2*goe*s^2 + 
 R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*goh*s^2 + R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*goi*s^2 + 
 R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*goa*s^2 + 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*go1*goa*goe*s^2 - 
 2.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1*go5^2*goe*goh*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm9*go1^2*goe*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm9*go1^2*goe*goi*s^2 ;
 A4=- 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gmQ2*go1^2*goa*goe*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gmQ1*go1^2*goa*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gmQ1*go1^2*goa*goi*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gmQ1*go5^2*gob*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*gm1^2*goa*gob*goe*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gmQ2*go5^2*goe*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ2*go5*goe*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gmQ1*go5^2*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*go5*goh*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*gmQ1*go5^2*goi*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*go5*goi*s^2 + R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*goe*goh*s^2 + 
 R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gm9*goe*goi*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5^2*goc*s^2 + 
 R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ2*goa*goe*s^2 + R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*goa*goh*s^2 + 
 R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*goa*goi*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*go1^2*goa*goe*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*go1^2*goa*goe*goi*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cdg1^2*go5^2*gob*goe*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*go5^2*goe*goh*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*go5*goe*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5*go5^2*goe*goi*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*go5*goe*goi*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ2*go5^2*goc*goe*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ1*go5^2*goc*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*gmQ1*go5^2*goc*goi*s^2 + R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*goa*goe*goh*s^2 + 
 R1^2*cgs1^2*gm5^2*goa*goe*goi*s^2 - 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*go5^2*goc*goe*goh*s^2 - 
 1.0*R1^2*cgs1^2*go5^2*goc*goe*goi*s^2 - 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*goh + 
 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5^2*goh + 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5*goh + 
 2.0*R1^2*gm5*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*goh - 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ2*goe*goh - 
 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*goh*goi - 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*goa*goh - 
 1.0*R1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*gob*goh - 1.0*R1^2*gm1*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1*go5^2*goh - 
 1.0*R1^2*gm5*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*go5*goh + 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5*gmQ2*go5^2*goe*goh + 
 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ2*go5*goe*goh + 2.0*R1^2*gm5*gm9*gmQ2*go1^2*goe*goh + 
 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5*gmQ1*go5^2*goh*goi + 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ1*go5*goh*goi + 
 2.0*R1^2*gm5*gm9*gmQ1*go1^2*goh*goi - 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gm9*goe*goh*goi + 
 2.0*R1^2*gm5*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*goa*goh + R1^2*gm5*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5^2*gob*goh + 
 R1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5*gob*goh + 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gmQ1*gmQ2*go5^2*goc*goh + 
 R1^2*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*goc*goh + R1^2*gm9*gmQ1*gmQ2*go1^2*god*goh - 
 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ2*goa*goe*goh - 1.0*R1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ2*gob*goe*goh - 
 2.0*R1^2*gm1*gm5^2*gmQ1*goa*goh*goi - 1.0*R1^2*gm5^2*gm9*gmQ1*gob*goh*goi - 
 1.0*R1^2*gm5^2*gmQ1*gmQ2*goa*gob*goh - 1.0*R1^2*gm1*gmQ2*go1*go5^2*goe*goh - 
 1.0*R1^2*gm5*gmQ2*go1^2*go5*goe*goh ;     


  Den=A0+A1+A2+A3+A4;
  toc
```

Comment: Where does that expression come from? It looks like it was computer-generated? It has lots of repeated operations, I’m sure it can be simplified. Maybe whatever process generates the expression can be adjusted to produce a simplified expression.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I was solving a symbolic matrix. And this is the result of it. I don't know how to simplify it more. So is simplifying the expression the only way to speedup calculating it?

Comment: Ah, you should solve your matrix equation numerically, always.https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

Comment: No. I do want to solve it symbolically since I need this expression. I use this expression to compute other things in other functions.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to do it this way. Remember how you're asking to make the code faster? Solve the equations numerically. It's faster and maybe even with less numerical errors because the operations can be optimized for badly conditioned matrices etc. You really do not want to do it this way.

Comment: Can you give an example for how you use this expression elsewhere? I presume you can only use this expression to solve a system of linear equations. What is the other thing you do with it?

Comment: OK. I will try solving it numerically. Thank you.

Comment: So I calculate the loop gain of a circuit symbolically. Then, I use this symbolic expression to extract the phase margin out of it. And the problem is I need to compute this expression thousands of times. Notice that I solved the matrix only once. I don't need it anymore. I just use this expression for further processing (phase margin calculation).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I didn't notice your last comment.

Comment: I solved it numerically, and yeah this speeds up the calculations by an order of magnitude. Thank you very much.